# Dependency Injection with constructor arguments

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

I've an **EJB** as follows:

```
public class Bar() {

     private String s;

     public Bar() {
         this.s = "bar";
     }

     @Inject public Bar(String s) {
         this.s = s;
     }

}
```

1. How can I inject that bean by using the **arg-constructor** into another `Foo` class?
2. Then, I define the `Foo` class as EJB, with the aim to perform the **DI** for it into another class (for instance, a WebServlet). How can I inject a `Foo` class instance by passing a `String` to properly set up `Bar` arg-constructor as **inner-dependency**?
3. Is there a better way to define `Bar` in order to achieve points above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The annotated constructor injection tells CDI that whenever someone requests an instance of Bar to be injected, it should use the constructor marked with @Inject.

The CDI container then  tries to get instances for all required constructor parameters and fails, because it can not deal with "String". It just doesn't know which String you mean.

You have to help the container resolving the dependency by using a Producer and a Qualifier to tell him what String you want. I just give you the simplest possible solution here:

```
public class Bar {

 @Inject 
 public Bar(@Named("myString") String s) {
     this.s = s;
 }
}
```

And then another class (doesn't have to be an different class, but its much more readable):

```
public class MyStringProducer {
  @Produces
  @Named("myString")
  public String getMyString() {
    return ...; // whatever you want ... read JSON, parse properties, randomize ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. There are some things still not clear (for me): how can I choose one of the two different constructors when I perform the injection?

Comment: @Inject can apply to at most one constructor per class http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html

Comment: I don't understand what should I put into `getMyString()` function, string s is not fixed and I can only get it in the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`@Inject` only works when you are injecting "`managed`" objects. String is not a managed object, thus this won;t work.

However, the following example should work (I have used spring here. Use the DI initializaton code according to the library you are using):

```
@Named
public class Foo {

    @Inject
    Bar bar;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.pkg1");
        Foo foo = (Foo)ctx.getBean("foo");

        System.out.println(foo.bar.getString());

    }


}

@Named
public class Bar {
    private String s;
    public Bar() {
        this.s = "bar";
    }
   @Inject 
   public Bar(Bar1 bar1) {
        this.s = bar1.getS();
    }
    public String getString() {
        return s;
    }
}

@Named
class Bar1 {
    private String s="bar1";
    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }
}
```